# Tab key not listening for CustomViewRenderer in Xamarin forms iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin forms grid and a written custom renderer for that grid in xamarin forms iOS platform. And applied BecomeFirstResposnder to that CustomRenderer on OnElementPropertyChanged. Added UIKeyCommand "\t
" to the UIViewController. UpArrow,DownArrow, LeftArrow every key is listening except Tab and Shift+Tab Key. Kindly, please help me.

//CustomRenderer for Xamarin Forms Grid

```cs
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    this.BecomeFirstResponder();
    if (this.KeyPageRenderer == null)
    {
        this.KeyPageRenderer = this.GetSfPageRenderer(this.GetControl());
        if (this.KeyPageRenderer != null)
        {
            UIKeyCommand KeyTab = UIKeyCommand.Create(new NSString("\t"), 0, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("KeyRecV:"));
            this.KeyPageRenderer.AddKeyCommand(KeyTab);
        }
    }
}

internal UIViewController GetSfPageRenderer(UIView view)
{
    if (view != null)
    {
        var responder = (UIResponder)view;
        while (responder != null && !(responder is UIViewController))
        {
            responder = responder.NextResponder;
        }
        return responder as UIViewController;
    }
    return null;
}

public override bool CanBecomeFirstResponder
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
[Export("KeyRecV:")]
private void Excute(UIKeyCommand keyCommand)
{
    if ((keyCommand.Input as NSObject).Description == "\t")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I found a way to get a notification tab key for my view. :)